# Is it safe to plug a computer into itself?

Tags: usb, audio, connector, microphone, motherboard

I have a USB dongle (with microphone and headphone 3.5mm jacks). Is it safe to plug the headphone out into my motherboard microphone/line in?

Would there be any grounding, feedback, impedance problems?

How loud could the USB dongle headphone out volume be without damaging the microphone/line in?

My setup would be: microphone - USB dongle microphone in - computer - USB dongle headphone out - 3.5mm jack extender cable - motherboard microphone/line in

Thank you.

Comment: This is safer than plugging the microphone from other device in terms of grounding. Other facts  is a matter of signal compatibility, only.

Comment: I'd expect that to be fine.

Comment: Would there be any problems with having it plugged in to itself when the computer is turned on and off?